# Need help on how to Reset the powerstate of multiple VM's similar to obtaining multiple VM's powerstate using a VMware Dynamic Inventory File

Tags: ansible, vmware-vcenter, ansible-playbook, json, yaml

I am trying to create and use a playbook that will reset the power of ONE, TWO or ALL VM's similiar to the playbook I use to obtain the powerstate of ONE, TWO or ALL VM's.

Here is my current setup and some basic background of something that works and is very flexible in terms of gathering VM information for a given group and it's variables.

***VMWARE DYNAMIC INVENTORY FILE = /home/me/ansible/hosts/vcenter_inventory_vmware.yml***

```
plugin: vmware_vm_inventory
strict: False
hostname: vcenter.mydomain.com
username: ansible_pscs_user@vsphere.local
password: **************
validate_certs: False
with_tags: False
groups:
  VMs: True
  windows: "'win' in config.guestId"
filters:
- summary.runtime.powerState == "poweredOn"
hostnames:
- config.name
```

***PLAYBOOK TO LIST ONLY POWERED ON WINDOWS VM's = /home/me/ansible/vmware_list_all_powered-on_windows_vms.yml***

```
 - hosts: windows
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
 - name: Gather a list of all powered on VMs
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      on_vm: "{{ all_vm_info.virtual_machines | json_query(query) }}"
    vars:
      query: "[?power_state=='poweredOn']"
    register: jsoncontent
```

***ANSIBLE COMMANDS AVAILABLE FOR ME TO USE***

```
ansible-playbook vmware_list_all_powered-on_windows_vms.yml = (This will display a list on all powered on windows VMs)
ansible-playbook vmware_list_all_powered-on_windows_vms.yml -l MYVMNAME = (This will display a powerstate of OK for MYVMNAME)
```

Now let's look at my VM power reset playbook and how I currently need to obtain variables.

***VARIABLE FILE = /home/me/ansible/hosts/group_vars/vmware.yml***

```
vcenter_hostname: vcenter.mydomain.com
vcenter_username: "ansible_pscs_user@vsphere.local"
vcenter_password: **************
vcenter_validate_certs: false
vm_name: MYVMNAME
```

***PLAYBOOK TO RESET THE POWER OF A SPECIFIC VM THAT RESIDES ON A SPECIFIC VCENTER = /home/me/ansible/vm_reset.yml***

```
- name: Power Cycle VM
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  pre_tasks:
    - include_vars: /home/me/ansible/hosts/group_vars/vmware.yml
  tasks:
    - name: VM Power Cycle
      community.vmware.vmware_guest_powerstate:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: "{{ vcenter_validate_certs }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
        state: restarted
        state_change_timeout: 120
      register: deploy
      ignore_errors: true
```

***ANSIBLE COMMANDS AVAILABLE FOR ME TO USE***

```
ansible-playbook vm_reset.yml = (This will reset the power of a single VM named MYVMNAME on a specific vcenter named vcenter.mydomain.com)
```

Now, here is what I what to achieve.  I want to perform a power reset of ONE, TWO or ALL VM's within a defined group within the VMWARE DYNAMIC INVENTORY and not have to use a separate variable file with redundant information.  As you will notice, the The VMWARE DYNAMIC INVENTORY gives me eveything I need (vcenter hostname, vcenter credentials, VM host groups and the ability to extract and use various VM variables for all or limited VM's.  I SHOULD NOT need to have a STATIC VARIABLE FILE called "/home/me/ansible/hosts/group_vars/vmware.yml" that contains information that can already be obtained from the VMWARE DYNAMIC INVENTORY "/home/me/ansible/hosts/vcenter_inventory_vmware.yml"

***ANSIBLE COMMANDS I WOULD LIKE AVAILABLE FOR ME TO USE***

```
ansible-playbook vm_reset.yml = (This should reset the power of all on all windows VMs)
ansible-playbook vm_reset.yml -l MYVMNAME = (This should reset the power of the MYVMNAME)
ansible-playbook vm_reset.yml -l MYVMNAME:ANOTHERVMNAME  = (This should reset the power of the MYVMNAME AND ANOTHERVMNAME)
```